# How to manage page in smaller sizes in Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

```
<div class="input-group col-sm-10">
<span class="input-group-addon col-sm-4 text-right border">.$s['Surname'].</span>
<input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control  col-sm-6" name="msg" placeholder="Enter Marks">
```

[bad on small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grsCp.png)

Hi, I tried using 2 columns, however on cellphones the controls seem to behave differently

[good on large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM2SL.png)

How do i allow the controls to keep a regular size on small screens?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you say in the code col-sm-6 means from small size (576px) take this size

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

//

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6"></div>
```

This piece of code conveys the concept that

col-12: Normally occupies all columns smaller than small

col-sm-8: Occupies 8 columns from small mode onwards **(576px)**

col-md-6: Occupies 6 columns from Medium mode onwards **(768px)**

We could also use **col-lg** on demand, which varies depending on our needs.

I hope I understood what you meant and that I was able to help you well

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code,

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         Here col is used for auto width (if row has multiple elements in column so col width will be adjusted automatically by dividing them)
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
             Here col-12 is used so this will get entire width of the viewport (12 grids) as it is specified..
          </div>

          <div class="col">
             Here col is used so as above div has col-12 class so this col will get auto width and there is no more columns in this row so this will get 100% of width.
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Note: for small devices like mobile (<576px) only col is used and col itself uses all 12 grids but if we have multiple columns in row and we want to give different grids to them, then we have to specify as col-6, col-4, col-12 etc as per requirement...

for more details i have attached some links and snap FYI...

[Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/)
[image: Bootstrap Grid System Column Details]
[image: Grids]

Thanks...
Alap Joshi

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

It will work fine for you

Comment: Duplicate/Copy. This is the same code as @davood beheshti, and he explained what it does.